# How can get_string error get avoided?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm doing the CS50 course, pset2 initials. The only error I get is a problem with get_string: it would have an 'incompatible pointer types initializing 'string' with an expression of type 'string (void)'. I really don't understand what I am doing wrong, because my code for get_string worked for the last problem set.. Here's my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    // ask user for input 
    printf("What are your names?");
    string s = get_string;    

    // print first letter from string & capitalize
    printf("%c", toupper(s[0]));


    //iterate over characters in current string + start loop
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        //find space character
        if (s[i] == ' ')
        {    
            // print character next to space & capitalize
            printf("%c", toupper(s[i++]));
        }
    // new rule 
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `string s = get_string;` ----> `string s = get_string();`

Comment: And, you don't seem to include `<string>` (unless it's included indirectly). `<string.h>` is a C header, and not the same as `<string>`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius The CS50 course was designed by some amateur who thought `typedef char* string;` was a brilliant idea. Turns out CS50 is just yet another crappy internet tutorial like the rest of them to avoid.

Comment: `toupper(s[i++])` should be `toupper(s[i])`. You already have i++ in the loop.

Comment: @Lundin Oh, I see.. Somehow, my brain automatically goes to C++ constructs, when the question is tagged with C++ - failing to consider other alternatives (while simultaneously failing to see _any_ C++ constructs being used) :/

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius It is a perfectly understandable mistake to do, given that `string` is such an incredibly well-known C++ class, known by every programmer in the world except for the teachers at Harvard uni...

Comment: Can I recommend that we remove the `c` tag and retain the `cs50` tag?  A `c` programmer (like me) has no idea what a `string` type is - and would likely replace the `c` tag with `c++`.

Answer (score 1):

Although you have not shown us `cs50.h`, we can guess that `get_string` is a function, so this:

```
string s = get_string;
```

Needs to be:

```
string s = get_string();
```

Comment: Thank you soo much!

Answer (score 1):

[get_string](https://reference.cs50.net/cs50/get_string) is a function that takes no parameters:

```
string get_string(void);
```

so

```
string s = get_string;
```

must be

```
string s = get_string();
```